# Multiple Carousels on same page using AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have search alot but i did not find any suaitable answer for my question that is why i am asking question here.

My question is very straight forward. I am working on shopping site where i have a landing page. On landing page there would be multiple carousels like Top carousel which showing banners, new arrivals carousel, top selling carousel and etc.

We are not going to use any jquery in this project instead each and ever thing will be handle by angularjs only. We want to implement all carousel using angulajs only not going use jquery any manner.

Please help us me in this regards as i am newbie in angular js.

Comment: twitter bootstrap's default carousel requires jquery and will not work otherwise. Search online for an angular carousel

Comment: I have already implement angular js carousel, but adding another i am getting error. like this "Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngController, carousel] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel" ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()" interval="myInterval" ng-controller="newArivalController">"

Comment: And please do not down vot as it is very important question. anybody can fall in this situation.

Comment: I did not down vote you, but someone did because you did not include enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at UI-bootstrap:

> Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel